# Lambda function not working with cloud formation deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to build out an app with an api gateway and a node back end running on lambda.

The node backend is very basic with express and sequelize. It isn't hooked up to a database yet. I can run the node app locally, navigate to an end point and get the standard "hello world" response that I send back from that end point.

When I build and deploy the stack, it shows that the code deployed to an s3 bucket and that the api and lambda were updated. However, I get the following error when trying to access an end point -

```
502 Bad Gateway - "message": "Internal server error"
```

Again, there is no logic on the back end, just a text response sent back. I have no idea how to address this. It doesn't seem to be an API issue, although I don't know how to test that. If it is an issue with the lambda deploy, why does it work locally?

In addition to this, the api gateway created by the cloudformation file has a "dev" stage and a "Stage" stage. I am not sure how this happened or if it is a problem.

Below is the yaml file.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Storygraf backend API
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
Resources:
  ExpressApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
  ExpressLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: s3://storygraf-backend/xxxx
      Handler: lambda.handler
      MemorySize: 512
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        ProxyApiRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ExpressApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
        ProxyApiGreedy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ExpressApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
```

Comment: That's probably a lambda integration error. Can you provide your lambda code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should [**activate logs**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-methodsettings) to be able to troubleshoot:

```yaml
  ExpressApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: "/*"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          DataTraceEnabled: true
          LoggingLevel: INFO # Or ERROR
      OpenApiVersion: 3.0.1 # This will remove the stage Stage
```

---

Note about [**`OpenApiVersion`**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-openapiversion):

> Note: Setting this property to any valid value will also remove the stage Stage that SAM creates.

---

Then copy your `apiId`:
[image: Api ID]

Send your request to your API and go to **CloudWatch**, there should be a Log Group named `API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{apiId}/dev` (you can paste your `apiId` in the search box to find it).

In there you can see detailed logs about the request and integration.

---

You most likely have an error like:

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response

Because lambda response should at least contain a `statusCode` field:

> With the Lambda proxy integration, the Lambda function must return output of the following format:
>
> ````
>     statusCode: "...",            // a valid HTTP status code
>     headers: { 
>         custom-header: "..."      // any API-specific custom header
>     },
>     body: "...",                  // a JSON string.
>     isBase64Encoded:  true|false  // for binary support } ```
> ````

---

See [API Gateway developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) and specifically:

- [Getting Started](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html)
- [Integration Response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html)
- [Lambda Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integrations.html)